# Implementing and tuning a simple CNN for 3D data using Keras Conv3D

Tags: keras, deep-learning, hyperparameters, conv-neural-network, model-fitting

I'm trying to implement a 3D CNN using Keras. However, I am having some difficulties understanding some details in the results obtained and further enhancing the accuracy.

The data that I am trying to analyzing have the shape {64(d1)x64(d2)x38(d3)}, where d1 and d2 are the length and width of the image (64x64 pixels) and d3 is the time dimension. In other words, I have 38 images. The channel parameter is set to 1 as my data are actually raw data and not really colorful images.

My data consist of 219 samples, hence 219x64x64x38. They are divided into training and validation sets with 20% for validation. In addition, I have a fixed 147 additional data for testing.

Below is my code that works fine. It creates a txt file that saves the results for the different combination of parameters in my network (grid search). Here in this code, I only consider tuning 2 parameters: the number of filters and lambda for L2 regularizer. I fixed the dropout and the kernel size for the filters. However, later I considered their variations.

I also tried to set the seed value so that I have some sort of reproducibility (I don't think that I have achieved this task).

**My question is that:**
Given the below architecture and code, I always reach for all the given combinations of parameters a convergence for the training accuracy towards 1 (which is good). However, for the validation accuracy it is most of the time around 80% +/- 4% (rarely below 70%) despite the hyper-parameters combination. Similar behavior for the test accuracy. How can I enhance this accuracy to above 90% ? 
As far as I know, having a gap between the train and validation/test accuracy is a result from overfitting. However, in my model I am adding dropouts and L2 regularizers and also changing the size of my network which should somehow reduce this gap (but it is not).

Is there anything else I can do besides modifying my input data? Does adding more layers help? Or is there maybe a pre-trained 3D CNN like in the case of 2D CNN (e.g., AlexNet)? Should I try ConvLSTM? Is this the limit of this architecture?

Thank you :)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Dense, Flatten, Activation
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import scipy.io as sio
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau

tf.set_random_seed(1234)

def normalize_minmax(X_train):
    """
    Normalize to [0,1]
    """
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    X_minmax_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    return X_minmax_train

# generate and prepare the dataset
def get_data():
    # Load and prepare the data
    X_data = sio.loadmat('./X_train')['X_train']
    Y_data = sio.loadmat('./Y_train')['targets_train'] 
    X_test = sio.loadmat('./X_test')['X_test']
    Y_test = sio.loadmat('./Y_test')['targets_test']
    return X_data, Y_data, X_test, Y_test

def get_model(X_train, Y_train, X_validation, Y_validation, F1_nb, F2_nb, F3_nb, kernel_size_1, kernel_size_2, kernel_size_3, l2_lambda, learning_rate, reduce_lr, dropout_conv1, dropout_conv2, dropout_conv3, dropout_dense, no_epochs):
    no_classes = 5
    sample_shape = (64, 64, 38, 1)
    batch_size = 32 
    dropout_seed = 30
    conv_seed = 20

    # Create the model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv3D(F1_nb, kernel_size=kernel_size_1, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_lambda), padding='same', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', input_shape=sample_shape))
    model.add(Activation('selu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_conv1, seed=conv_seed))

    model.add(Conv3D(F2_nb, kernel_size=kernel_size_2, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_lambda), padding='same', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(Activation('selu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_conv2, seed=conv_seed))

    model.add(Conv3D(F3_nb, kernel_size=kernel_size_3, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_lambda), padding='same', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(Activation('selu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_conv3, seed=conv_seed))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_lambda), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(Activation('selu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_dense, seed=dropout_seed))
    model.add(Dense(no_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus = 2)
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    # Train the model.
    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=no_epochs, validation_data=(X_validation, Y_validation),callbacks=[reduce_lr])
    return model, history

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=0.0001)
learning_rate = 0.001
no_epochs = 100

X_data, Y_data, X_test, Y_test = get_data()

# Normalize the train/val data
for i in range(X_data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(X_data.shape[3]):
        X_data[i,:,:,j] = normalize_minmax(X_data[i,:,:,j])
X_data = np.expand_dims(X_data, axis=4)


# Normalize the test data
for i in range(X_test.shape[0]):
    for j in range(X_test.shape[3]):
        X_test[i,:,:,j] = normalize_minmax(X_test[i,:,:,j])
X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=4)


# Shuffle the training data
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seedValue = 40
permutation = np.random.RandomState(seed=seedValue).permutation(len(X_data))
X_data = X_data[permutation]
Y_data = Y_data[permutation]
Y_data = np.squeeze(Y_data)
Y_test = np.squeeze(Y_test)

#Split between train and validation (20%). Here I did not use the classical validation_split=0.2 just to make sure that the data is the same for the different architectures I am using.
X_train = X_data[0:175,:,:,:,:]
Y_train = Y_data[0:175]
X_validation = X_data[176:,:,:,:]
Y_validation = Y_data[176:]

Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train,num_classes=5).astype(np.integer)
Y_validation = to_categorical(Y_validation,num_classes=5).astype(np.integer)
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test,num_classes=5).astype(np.integer)

l2_lambda_list = [(1*pow(10,-4)),(2*pow(10,-4)),
                  (3*pow(10,-4)),
                  (4*pow(10,-4)),
                  (5*pow(10,-4)),(6*pow(10,-4)),
                  (7*pow(10,-4)),
                  (8*pow(10,-4)),(9*pow(10,-4)),(10*pow(10,-4))
                  ]

filters_nb = [(128,64,64),(128,64,32),(128,64,16),(128,64,8),(128,32,32),(128,32,16),(128,32,8),(128,16,8),(128,8,8),
              (64,64,32),(64,64,16),(64,64,8),(64,32,32),(64,32,16),(64,32,8),(64,16,16),(64,16,8),(64,8,8),
              (32,32,16),(32,32,8),(32,16,16),(32,16,8),(32,8,8),
              (16,16,16),(16,16,8),(16,8,8)
              ]

DropOut = [(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.5),
           (0,0,0,0.1),(0,0,0,0.2),(0,0,0,0.3),(0,0,0,0.4),(0,0,0,0.5),
           (0.1,0.1,0.1,0),(0.2,0.2,0.2,0),(0.3,0.3,0.3,0),(0.4,0.4,0.4,0),(0.5,0.5,0.5,0),
           (0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1),(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2),(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3),(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.4),(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.5),
           (0.15,0.15,0.15,0.1),(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.2),(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.3),(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.4),(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.5),
           (0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1),(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2),(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3),(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4),(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.5),
           (0.25,0.25,0.25,0.1),(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.2),(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.3),(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.4),(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.5),
           (0.3,0.3,0.3,0.1),(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.2),(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3),(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4),(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.5),
           (0.35,0.35,0.35,0.1),(0.35,0.35,0.35,0.2),(0.35,0.35,0.35,0.3),(0.35,0.35,0.35,0.4),(0.35,0.35,0.35,0.5)
           ]

kernel_size = [(3,3,3),
               (2,3,3),(2,3,4),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,3,7),(2,3,8),(2,3,9),(2,3,10),(2,3,11),(2,3,12),(2,3,13),(2,3,14),(2,3,15),
               (3,3,3),(3,3,4),(3,3,5),(3,3,6),(3,3,7),(3,3,8),(3,3,9),(3,3,10),(3,3,11),(3,3,12),(3,3,13),(3,3,14),(3,3,15),
               (3,4,3),(3,4,4),(3,4,5),(3,4,6),(3,4,7),(3,4,8),(3,4,9),(3,4,10),(3,4,11),(3,4,12),(3,4,13),(3,4,14),(3,4,15), 
              ]

for l in range(len(l2_lambda_list)):
    l2_lambda = l2_lambda_list[l]
    f = open("My Results.txt", "a")
    lambda_Str = str(l2_lambda)
    f.write("---------------------------------------\n")
    f.write("lambda = "+f"{lambda_Str}\n")
    f.write("---------------------------------------\n")

    for i in range(len(filters_nb)):
        F1_nb = filters_nb[i][0]
        F2_nb = filters_nb[i][1]
        F3_nb = filters_nb[i][2]

        kernel_size_1 = kernel_size[0]
        kernel_size_2 = kernel_size_1
        kernel_size_3 = kernel_size_1

        dropout_conv1 = DropOut[0][0]
        dropout_conv2 = DropOut[0][1]
        dropout_conv3 = DropOut[0][2]
        dropout_dense = DropOut[0][3]
        # fit model
        model, history = get_model(X_train, Y_train, X_validation, Y_validation, F1_nb, F2_nb, F3_nb, kernel_size_1, kernel_size_2, kernel_size_3, l2_lambda, learning_rate, reduce_lr, dropout_conv1, dropout_conv2, dropout_conv3, dropout_dense, no_epochs)

        # Evaluate metrics
        predictions = model.predict(X_test)
        out = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
        Y_test = sio.loadmat('./Y_test')['targets_test']
        Y_test = np.squeeze(Y_test)

        loss = history.history['loss'][no_epochs-1]
        acc = history.history['acc'][no_epochs-1]
        val_loss = history.history['val_loss'][no_epochs-1]
        val_acc = history.history['val_acc'][no_epochs-1]

        # accuracy: (tp + tn) / (p + n)
        accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, out)
        # f1: 2 tp / (2 tp + fp + fn)
        f1 = f1_score(Y_test, out,average='macro')

        a = str(filters_nb[i][0]) + ',' + str(filters_nb[i][1]) + ',' + str(filters_nb[i][2]) + ':  ' + str('f1-metric: ') + str('%f' % f1) + str(' | loss: ') + str('%f' % loss) + str(' | acc: ') + str('%f' % acc) + str(' | val_loss: ') + str('%f' % val_loss) + str(' | val_acc: ') + str('%f' % val_acc) + str(' | test_acc: ') + str('%f' % accuracy) 
        f.write(f"{a}\n")

    f.close()
```

Comment: I think ConvLSTM would be better than a 3D CNN.

Comment: Do you recommend a good tutorial for ConvLSTM?